# Get value for JSON key with few dynamic characters

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem statement where I need to find value of a key where I might have to escape few words while searching.

Example :

```json
{"The length is {value} " : "done"}
```

I should get the output "done" if I search for **The length is 10**, or **The length is 20**. I am trying to get this done in php.

Comment: you can use json_decode function.this function return your json convert in array after get your value is easily get

Comment: @ParasRaiyani could you please elaborate how I will get the value from array with one or multiple word to exclude?

Answer (score 0):

First turn your json into an array with json_decode($json, true)
You can create a variable like $key = "The length is" . $number;
And then use key_exist function to check if the $Key exist in your array.

If it exist then you can get the value by key name from your array

Comment: I don't know where the $number will be. I will just have a string The length is 10. But I can create Json key like The length is {length} and I have to escape the {length}.

Answer (score 0):

1. decode your json using json_decode() function
2. get key json array using array_keys() function
3. get first key pass in json array and get your value
4. Like this:

`$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
$key_array = array_keys($json_array);
echo $json_array[$key_array[0]];`